# Getting "Taken Date" of a photo instead of "Modified Date" with PHP exif_read_data

Tags: php, image, exif

I'm retrieving the creation date from a photo with exif_read_data PHP function (see the code below.) The dates retrieved from photos that haven't been modified return "Date Taken". Those that have been modified - "Date Modified". Is there a way to get the date a photo was taken, ignoring the "Date Modified" field?

```
$exif_data = exif_read_data ($filename);
if (!empty($exif_data['DateTime'])) {
    $exif_date = $exif_data['DateTime'];
}
```

Thank you.

Edit: I think $exif_data['DateTime'] uses the first available date field. Since unmodified images had the same value for "Date Modified" and "Date Taken" it was always retrieving "Date Modified" in my case.

Answer (score 14):

Okay, I know this is a bit late as this question was posted a year ago, but I am posting this answer because I had the same question and my husband showed me a trick or two about how to get the answer, so I am sharing it.
Write a php script to print out the exif_read_data array and you will find all sorts of interesting information. This (below) was printed on command line to stdout using print_r(). If you scroll down you will see two very interesting keys:
  [DateTime] => 2011:06:21 17:50:57 and  [DateTimeOriginal] => 2011:06:04 08:56:22

I hope these will help you get what you need.

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => Pirate(F).JPG
    [FileDateTime] => 1405733742
    [FileSize] => 4017033
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, COMMENT, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="2592" height="3888"
            [Height] => 3888
            [Width] => 2592
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 1
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/16.0
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [Make] => Canon
    [Model] => Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XS
    [Orientation] => 1
    [XResolution] => 4718592/65536
    [YResolution] => 4718592/65536
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => QuickTime 7.6.9
    [DateTime] => 2011:06:21 17:50:57
    [HostComputer] => Mac OS X 10.5.8
    [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 260
    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 4718592/65536
            [YResolution] => 4718592/65536
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 628
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 4867
            [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
        )

    [COMMENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => AppleMark

        )

    [ExposureTime] => 1/200
    [FNumber] => 16/1
    [ExposureProgram] => 2
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 400
    [ExifVersion] => 0220
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2011:06:04 08:56:22
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 2011:06:04 08:56:22
    [ShutterSpeedValue] => 499712/65536
    [ApertureValue] => 524288/65536
    [ExposureBiasValue] => 0/1
    [MeteringMode] => 5
    [Flash] => 9
    [FocalLength] => 18/1
    [ColorSpace] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 11):

The solution is easier then I thought. I was referring to a wrong tag. To get date taken use:

$exif_data['DateTimeOriginal'];

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "test1.jpg:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test1.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
    echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
}
}
```

will output

```
test1.jpg:
No header data found.
test2.jpg:
FILE.FileName: test2.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1017666176
FILE.FileSize: 1240
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, COMMENT
COMPUTED.html: width="1" height="1"
COMPUTED.Height: 1
COMPUTED.Width: 1
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1
COMPUTED.UserComment: Exif test image.
COMPUTED.UserCommentEncoding: ASCII
COMPUTED.Copyright: Photo (c) M.Boerger, Edited by M.Boerger.
COMPUTED.Copyright.Photographer: Photo (c) M.Boerger
COMPUTED.Copyright.Editor: Edited by M.Boerger.
IFD0.Copyright: Photo (c) M.Boerger
IFD0.UserComment: ASCII
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 134
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 523
COMMENT.0: Comment #1.
COMMENT.1: Comment #2.
COMMENT.2: Comment #3end
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 134
THUMBNAIL.Thumbnail.Height: 1
THUMBNAIL.Thumbnail.Height: 1
```

source http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Thank you so much, i got my wedding photos into right order!

Answer (score 3):

DateTime info exists in the Image File Directory (IFD) which a recurring data structure within the [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data. To get taken date of photo and represent as a native php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object, you need to fetch it from right IFD section :

```
<?php
$filename  = "/path/to/your/image.jpg";
$exifData  = exif_read_data( $filename, 'IFD0');
$takenDate = NULL;

if( $exifData !== FALSE ) {
  if( array_key_exists('DateTime', $exifData ) ) {
    $takenDate = new DateTime( $exifData['DateTime'] );
  } else {
    // No DateTime field available
  }

} else {
  // No exif data available
}
```

After that you can validate the exif DateTime data simply:

```
is_null( $takenDate );
```

Comment: DateTime() will not convert a Unix timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure where you got your information but [exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) information is dependent on the image or captured device. Even if its modified the exif can sill be striped

Example

```
array (size=7)
  'FileName' => string 'img.jpg' (length=7)
  'FileDateTime' => int 1332747844
  'FileSize' => int 22569
  'FileType' => int 2
  'MimeType' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'SectionsFound' => string 'IFD0' (length=4)
  'COMPUTED' => 
    array (size=5)
      'html' => string 'width="338" height="506"' (length=24)
      'Height' => int 506
      'Width' => int 338
      'IsColor' => int 1
      'ByteOrderMotorola' => int 0
```

This is a valid `exif` information but does not include

- Datetime
- DateTaken
- DateModified
- DateTimeOriginal
- DateTimeDigitized

You really need to rethink your strategy and work with `FileDateTime` thats the only information am aware always present

Comment: FileDateTime probably gets file modification time only and (probably) is a system command.

Photographic devices always have "date taken" field and I need to retrieve it. The function above works perfectly fine (for my needs) with unmodified photos. When I edit them in Photoshop and re-save them, the function uses the "date modified" field. Files still have the "date taken" field with correct time, so it is definitively possible to retrieve it.

Comment: Verify again ... i have over 1000 pictures tested ...  a typical example is `SAMSUNG GT-N7000` mobile phone  it only has `Datetime , DateTimeOriginal , DateTimeDigitized` .. am sure you can easily verify that your self ... and please note that exif information can easily be switched on on some device