# Get image create date in PHP GD

Tags: php, metadata, gd

I have a case: I took a photo. Now I want to read date of the created photo (the shooting photo date) using GD.

Is it possible to get this date created from the image metadata?

Comment: I don't think GD can do this.  Have a look at [`exif_read_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php).

Comment: I agree with @RocketHazmat, I can't find anything relating to time on http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: I try to use exif_read_data, but presented there entry `FILE.FileDateTime` is last touch date.

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski: Are there any other dates in there?  A `DateTimeOriginal` maybe?  (I found that info from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13676478)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Taken Date" of a photo instead of "Modified Date" with PHP exif\_read\_data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674296/getting-taken-date-of-a-photo-instead-of-modified-date-with-php-exif-read-da)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exif_read_data() function instead, you will get everything you'd need :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Look for the particular Exif data with a key DateTimeOriginal.

Make sure that the software you are using are not stripping the actual exif. For example if you are using Photoshop, doing a "Save as JPG" retains the exif but "Export for web and devices" does not.

Comment: Please read my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692596/get-image-create-date-in-php-gd#comment29250237_19692596

Comment: use $exif_data['DateTimeOriginal']

Comment: At an array is no `DateTimeOriginal` key.

Comment: I think then the software you are using are stripping that value. Can you please try it with a picture directly from the camera? Or if you are using a software like photoshop do a "Save As JPG" instead of "Export for Web and Devices" to retain the complete exif.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. If photo wasn't correct exported there wasn't write correct original date ;)