# read XMP description field with php

Tags: php

Is there a way to specify a specific XMP data field that I want to read of a JPG image with php? In my case, I'd like to read the description field.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692596/get-image-create-date-in-php-gd for info on metadata in Boutell's GD.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Better still, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: I tried exif, but the specific data field I want, description, is not available through that platform. Thanks for the php link!

Comment: You could try this instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php

Comment: Thanks, I think that one could work, I'll update thread if so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys,

I was able to get the exact field I wanted by using iptcparse to create an array and then calling the index I wanted:

```
$size = getimagesize('./NIGERIA_95-12.JPG', $info);
if(isset($info['APP13']))
{
$iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);

echo $iptc["2#120"][0];
}
```